# Pasting a range from a pivot table to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to get a unique range pfrom Sheet A (pivot summarizing my data on an irrelevant master sheet) to paste on another sheet Sheet B (New Blank sheet). Below is my code for this. I get a runtime error "AdvancedFilter method of Range class failed". I have literally tried everything for hours and have no idea what else to do.

```
Public Function FindRow(ByVal sht As Worksheet, ByVal r As Long, ByVal c As Long, ByVal Match As Variant) As Long

    Do While Cells(r, c) <> Match
    r = r + 1
    Loop

    FindRow = r

End Function

Sub ExtractFromPivot()

    Dim PivotSheet As Worksheet
    Dim RandomSheet As Worksheet
    Dim Newsheet As Worksheet
    Dim Newbook As Workbook
    Dim Fundname As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim Copyrange As String
    Dim fr As Long
    Dim lr As Long

    Set RandomSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set PivotSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract Pivot")

    'Clears all filters on 'Name' (believe me I tried .clearallfilters
    With ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Client_Name")
        .SlicerItems("a").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("b").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("c").Selected = True
    End With


    lr = FindRow(PivotSheet, 30, 1, "")
    Let Copyrange = "A31" & ":" & "A" & lr

    PivotSheet.Range(Copyrange).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=RandomSheet.Cells(1, 1), Unique:=True
```

Comment: You need to `Set` your range. `Let` is deprecated or something that happened before I even learned VBA

Comment: `Set CopyRange = Range("A31:A" & lr)`... Then, `CopyRange.AdvancedFilter....`

Comment: When I change it to set, it gives me an error: "Object Required"

Comment: You not only need to use the Set keyword, but you also need to refer to your range using the Range property, as per @urdearboy in his second comment. Did you do so?

Comment: @domenic I replaced the line of code that began with let to: Set Copyrange = Range("A31:A" & lr)

Comment: For what it's worth, the let syntax works great in another macro, used in the same fashion.

Comment: Does it help if you specify the worksheet -- `Set Copyrange = PivotSheet.Range("A31:A" & lr)`?

Comment: It does not ://